# python, import package from parent dir

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

My project tree is like this:

```
maindir\
    dir1\
        MAINSCRIPT.py
    dir2\
        scriptA.py
```

The `MAINSCRIPT.py` is my main script!

How can I import `scriptA.py` from `MAINSCRIPT.py`

Answer (score 3):

Well this isn't technical a python package in the first place or it would have an `__init__.py` in each folder. And also I'm confused why you would have your main program in one of your folders. But something that I've used often to import a file that isn't in Python's regularly checked paths is

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '../dir2'); import scriptA
```

Hope that helps! 
For more info: [more on path insertion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath)